# C# Loop Ignores Conditional Statements

Tags: c#, loops, console-application

I have created a Dice-Simulator in a method within the class program.

And in the Main method im trying to create a loop to ask the user if he/she want's to play again.

For some reason the loop completely ignores my Conditional statements and I have no idea why.

It doesn't matter if I enter numbers or any gibberish, it still restarts the game.

The only thing that works is when I enter "N" or "n" to quit.

```
        string alt;
        do
        {
            GameLogic();

            Console.WriteLine("Play again?");
            Console.WriteLine("[Y]es | [N]o");

            alt = Console.ReadLine();
            alt.ToLower();

            if (alt == "Y" || alt == "y")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                GameLogic();
            }
            else if (alt == "N" || alt == "n")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");
            }
        } while (alt != "N" || alt != "n");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to quit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I expect it to do what conditions asks it to do. If you enter anything else other than "Y, y" or "N, n" it should show the message "Invalid input!".

It should only restart the game if you enter "Y" or "y".

Comment: `alt.ToLower()` *returns* a lowercased *copy* of the string, which you throw away unused. If you want `alt` to be lowercase, save the lowercased return string by assigning it back to `alt`: `alt = alt.ToLower();`.

Comment: What is `Control.WriteLine()`?

Comment: What is the input that is causing it to ignore your conditionals? Along with the comment by @EdPlunkett you should also just take the first character in case they send `yes` or `no`.

Comment: alt != "N" || alt != "n" - this statement will always be true. Until the end of time .

Comment: Move the first call to `GameLogic();` outside of the loop; `GameLogic(); do { ...`

Comment: @AllanJ  Please check my answer.  I added an extra variable and a condition.  Please mark as answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Ed, you are right about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a little bit off.

Try this code:

```
        string alt;
        bool firstRun = true;
        do
        {
            if (firstRun)
            {
                firstRun = false;
                GameLogic();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Play again?");
            Console.WriteLine("[Y]es | [N]o");

            alt = Console.ReadLine();
            alt.ToLower();

            if (alt == "Y" || alt == "y")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                GameLogic();
            }
            else if (alt == "N" || alt == "n")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");             
            }
        } while (alt != "N" || alt != "n");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to quit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Basically the GameLogic gets excuted at the beginning of your do while loop.

So you have to make sure it executes the first time then only if the person choose it will execute a second time.

Comment: There's a clearer and simpler way to express "Do this only once, before the first time the loop executes".

Comment: You solved it too! But I just moved it outside of the loop instead. Thank you!

Comment: @EdPlunkett agreed.. But I wrote it for the sake of simplicity.  So that a beginner can understand where the problem is.  This answer is designed to explain the situation rather then provide a solution to a production application.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it in a way... I had to move GameLogic(); outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes that also works.  I posted an answer that also works while keeping your loop in case you want to extract the loop into a method o it's own.  But that was exactly your problem